# Proving that the Riemann sum of $|f|$ is ≤ $f$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I need to prove $U_{|f |} (Z ) − L_{|f |} (Z ) ≤ U_f (Z ) − L_f (Z )$

Where $U$ is the upper estimate and $L$ is the lower estimate and $f$ is bounded.

I get that since $f$ is bounded, I have $m_j = inf(f)$ and $M_j = sup(f)$

Since $|f| ≥ f$, there is also $q_j = inf(|f|)$ and $Q_j = sup(|f|)$ and $q_j ≥ m_j, Q_j ≥ M_j$

So then
$U_{|f |} ≥ U_f (Z )$ and $L_{|f |} (Z ) ≥ L_f (Z )$

Which gives me two equalities and something like this when combined:
$$U_{|f |} (Z ) + L_{|f |} (Z ) ≥ U_f (Z ) + L_f (Z )$$ which is quite off.

How can I prove $U_{|f |} (Z ) − L_{|f |} (Z ) ≤ U_f (Z ) − L_f (Z )$?

Comment: Proving the inequality in the first line is not the same as proving that the Riemann sum of $|f|$ is $\le$ the Riemann sum of $f$.

Comment: Title of question is wrong ! and it's really not related to the problem you described in context of question. the problem in body of question just prove Reimann sum of $|f|$ converge quicker than Reimann sum of $f$. i put an answer for this below. hope it's helpful.

Comment: thank you, yes thats helpful. The terminiology is a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!read this answer after the comment i just put. 
if $M_j \geq 0$ then $Q_j=M_j$ , and since $q_j \geq m_j$:
$$
Q_j-q_j \leq M_j - m_j \tag{1}
$$
if $M_j <0$ then $f(x)$ is strictly negative on $\Delta x_j$, hence $|f(x)| = -f(x)$ therefore $Q_j = -m_j$ and $q_j = - M_j$ so :
$$
Q_j -q_j = -(m_j-M_j)=M_j-m_j. \tag{2}
$$
for every $j$ either $M_j \geq0$ or $M_j<0$ and in both case $Q_j-q_j \leq M_j - m_j$. so multiply this by length of $\Delta x_j$ and sum over all $j$:
$$
\sum_j (Q_j-q_j)\Delta x_j \leq \sum_j (M_j-m_j)\Delta x_j
$$
it's true for every partition $P$ and then take $||P|| \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: thank you, so I forgot to consider the cases when M is < and > 0

Comment: im not too sure how you got $=−$
 and $=− $ though...

Comment: when function is strictly negative, if you get its absolute value you multiply it by $(-1)$. so its supremum becomes infimum and vice versa. i mean if $f(x)<0$ then $\sup(|f(x)|) = -\inf (f(x))$.

Comment: nevermind i have figured it out